# How can I prevent gatsby to download remote files from WordPress?

Tags: gatsby, wp-graphql

Whenever I run `npm run develop` or `npm run build` gatsby downloads remote files from WordPress and stores them in a cache. Serve images and other static files from the cache.

Since it's downloading remote files every time it's taking a lot of time to complete the download and serve the application. which is not good for development.

I don't want it. I just simply want to use a remote URL to render images. How can I do that?

Comment: You're going to have to add more context here.

Comment: Could you suggest what should I add?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of options available to customize the behavior in the [`gatsby-source-wordpress`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md) plugin:

- `hardCacheMediaFiles` (experimental): when set to `true`, media files will be hard-cached outside the Gatsby cache at `./.wordpress-cache/path/to/media/file.jpeg.` This is useful for preventing media files from being re-downloaded when the Gatsby cache automatically clears. When using this option, be sure to gitignore the `wordpress-cache` directory in the root of your project.

  Usage:

  ```
  {
     resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
     options: {
       production: {
         hardCacheMediaFiles: true, // false by default
       },
     },
  }
  ```

  This option won't avoid downloading from the server, it will cache the images to avoid subsequent downloads.
- `excludeByMimeTypes`: allows preventing the download of files associated with `MediaItem` nodes by their mime types.

  Usage:

  ```
  {
     resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
     options: {
       type: {
         MediaItem: {
           localFile: {
             excludeByMimeTypes: [`video/mp4`], // add your images format
           },
         },
       },
     },
  }
  ```

  This option can potentially avoid downloading your images and the specified formats
- `maxFileSizeBytes`: allows preventing the download of files that are above a certain file size (in bytes). Default is 15mb.

  Usage:

  ```
  {
     resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
     options: {
       type: {
        MediaItem: {
           localFile: {
             maxFileSizeBytes: 10485760, // 10Mb. Set it to 0 to avoid downloads
           },
         },
       },
     },
  }
  ```

  This option can potentially avoid downloading assets from the server.